# Import data with Comma as decimal seperator and do calculations

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to read data from a csv and then do some calculations.
The problem here is the comma as a decimal separator. With a point as decimal seperator in my csv data everything woks but with a comma it does not. Are there any solutions available to solve my problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$]
\addplot [ 
           color=red, 
           only marks, 
           mark=*, 
           mark size=1.5pt, 
         ]
         table
         [ col sep=semicolon,
           /pgf/number format/read comma as period, 
           x=x, 
           y expr=\thisrow{y}*2  
         ] {test.csv}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The Data:

```
x;y
1;1
2;1
3;1
4;8,5
5;2
6;2
```

Comment: I suggest you use double quotes to limit data that uses commas as decimal separator, like so: "8,34","2,456","25,8".

Comment: crosspost http://golatex.de/daten-mit-komma-als-dezimaltrenner-einlesen-und-berechnen-t19606.html

Comment: You say comma `,` but show in your data a semicolon `;`.  Which is it?

Comment: The semicolon seperates the column. The semicolon is not the decimal seperator.

Comment: Dear logo_writer can you explain me the part with the quotes more in detail? Do I have to adjust my data therefor?